# Get max value from every index in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering how to get the max value from every key from a dictionary. Let's say I have this:

`dict={(1,1,True):[-1, 0.26], (2,1,True):[0.1, 0],(1,2,True):[0.01, -1],(2,2,True):[1, -0.11],}`

And this is the expected output:

`new_dict={(1,1,True):0, (2,1,True):0,(1,2,True):1,(2,2,True):0,}`

The new 0 and 1 values means the following:

- If the absolute max value is the first element, the output value will be 0. If not, 1.
- Example: Abs(-1), Abs(0.26)-> 1>0.26 -> 0 will be the expected output.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried and explain where the problem is?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page

Comment: Avoid using `dict` to name your variable as it's a Python keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only write what you say.

```
dct={
    (1,1,True):[-1, 0.26], 
    (2,1,True):[0.1, 0],
    (1,2,True):[0.01, -1],
    (2,2,True):[1, -0.11],
}

for key, value in dct.items():
    # check 'abs(item_zero) with 'abs(item_one)' as 'boolean' 
    # then convert 'False -> 0' and 'True -> 1'.
    dct[key] = int(abs(value[0]) <= abs(value[1]))
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{(1, 1, True): 0, (2, 1, True): 0, (1, 2, True): 1, (2, 2, True): 0}
```

Comment: You're welcome, have a good time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple `argmax` function, and do the rest with simple list/dict comprehensions.

```
def argmax(lst):
    return max(range(len(lst)), key=lambda i: lst[i])


my_dict = {(1, 1, True): [-1, 0.26], (2, 1, True): [0.1, 0], (1, 2, True): [0.01, -1], (2, 2, True): [1, -0.11], }
print({k: argmax([abs(v_) for v_ in v]) for k, v in my_dict.items()})
```

Note: It's not a good idea to override `dict`...

You can also maybe make things cleaner by putting the `abs` inside the argmax function:

```
def abs_argmax(lst):
    return max(range(len(lst)), key=lambda i: abs(lst[i]))


my_dict = {(1, 1, True): [-1, 0.26], (2, 1, True): [0.1, 0], (1, 2, True): [0.01, -1], (2, 2, True): [1, -0.11], }
print({k: abs_argmax(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()})
```